# Corner Bead With Stucco Over Mesh

Tags: masonry, stucco

I have a small wooden box closing the gap between the entry door and the original opening that I prepped with tar paper and mesh to apply stucco to so that it fits with the rest around.

Should I put a metal corner bead to straighten the edge (see picture) or should I go without the way it is?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it either way, I would use a corner bead, but use the variety that has expanded metal lathe on the edges too. Although corner could be done "freehand", using the trowel as a guide on one side and scraping the stucco over the edge of the trowel (an 18" concrete trowel) let that set, then do the same for the other side. This is done for the first two coats then the finish coat is done on both faces.
If you use a corner bead, you can build up both sides at the time doing the work in three steps instead of five. Make sure you hold the stucco back off the corner bead the appropriate amount for each layer, until the finish layer goes flush with the corner bead
I take it is a sanded finish? You may be able to eliminate a layer, just the scratch coat, then finish coat.

Comment: "the variety that has expanded metal lathe on the edges" -- any chance you can find some examples of such a product online?

Comment: http://www.phillipsmfg.com/products/svpbt/casing.htm

Comment: Hmm I hit enter for a new line and it posted and it would not let me edit it. Anyway the #1 is what I was referring to. Use the one in zinc, There is another style that would work too. here is that link too.http://www.lowes.com/pd_262475-46086-735373_?PL=1&productId=3375760  . It is available in zinc elsewhere. When it is all said and done the finished product should be somewhere 3/4" thick, it can be more or less. Let each layer set for a day. If the finish is sanded, that is done with a sponge float, after the material is set for an hour or so for a fine finish, less time for a coarse finish